# Empty Image renders in front of transparent object

Tags: image, transparency

I am trying to model with a reference image in Blender 2.80. I want to see both the reference image and my mesh in a transparent overlay so nothing blocks anything else. I assigned a material to my mesh and set its "Viewport Display" with an alpha of just less than one, so it should remain mostly transparent. However, the images that I pulled in render completely in front of it as soon as this transparency is added. Is it possible to make my mesh render transparently in front of an object?

the images rendering in front of the transparent mesh:
[image: the images rendering in front of the transparent mesh]

The alpha channel for the mesh's material: [image: the alpha channel for the mesh's material]]

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make the mesh transparent, but it seems the easier way is to make the images transparent. In the image's object data panel, click the "Use Alpha" checkbox, and adjust the transparency value. To get the desired effect, this needs to be set on the image *and* you need to set an alpha on the mesh's material's "viewport display" like I showed in the question.

[image: the image's object data panel]